# how can i get the material color form this code using jquery and three js

Tags: three.js

```
"materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "color_1.003",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.64000004529953, 0.64000004529953, 0.64000004529953],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.64000004529953, 0.64000004529953, 0.64000004529953],
        "colorEmissive" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a hex color value, and it seems plausable those values goes from 0 to 1 (as so often is the case with 3d programming).

1. Convert 0-1 range to a 0-255 range
2. Convert from decimal to hex
3. Put the values together to a string

`[0.64000, 0.23000000, 0.123456].map( v => Math.round(v*255).toString(16) ).join("")`

- `.map()` runs a function for every value in an array and returned values becomes a new array.
- `.join()` concats multiple values together to a string
- `Math.round()` to get rid of the ugly decimals
- `.toString()` converts to hex if you pass in a radix of 16.

The same thing could be rewritten for reusability and readability

```
function toHex(value){
    return Math.round(value*255).toString(16)
}

function toHexColor(arr){
    return "#" + arr.map(toHex).join("")
}

const color = toHexColor(materials[0].colorDiffuse)
console.log( color )
```

*Dislaimer: Those function names aren't great, but serves the purpose of a demonstration*